# ActiveAdmin: `default_actions` is no longer provided in ActiveAdmin 1.x. Use `actions` instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I just installed the newest version of active admin on github, running

`rails v. 3.2.17` on `ruby 2.0.0` `active-admin 1.0.0.pre1` @ `Windows 7`.

I am encountering following problem, if I login and go to the admin users tab:

[image: Error]

How can I fix this problem? I looked into the `active/admin/views/index_as_table.rb`, but `default_actions` is used by `actions`. I can't just rename it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using "actions" where you were using "default_actions"?

Comment: Hello this is the gist: the problem ist action is using default_actions https://gist.github.com/jensJJ/db2a4d049ef285c29e3d

Comment: The code you are attempting to use is not compatible with the version of ActiveAdmin you are using. You will have to update your application code or use a previous version of ActiveAdmin. Obviously the most future proof choice is going to me debugging and updating the code to work with the master branch of ActiveAdmin.

Comment: This is the master branch code. Should I delete everything again?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the issue you are having. It's possible that the code you are using in your application is not compatible with the version of the ActiveAdmin gem that is being loaded. If you have overridden the views and pulled them into your application code you may want to retry that process. I also notice that you are using Windows and I am not sure what the process for loading gems in on Win, sorry.

Comment: I destroyed the gem and all the migration files. Now re-installed from the latest branch and it works!